# Will these ajax calls delay page elements further down?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this pseudocode to retrieve some json files and put their content into the content div.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            var my_files = ['http://example.com/file.json', 'http://example.com/file2.json'];
            var params = {
                format: 'json'
            };
            function _populate_content(arg){jQuery("#content").text(arg)}
            jQuery(my_files.each(function() {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    data: params,
                    jsonpCallback: "_populate_content",
                });
            });
        </script>
        <div id="more_content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It might take some time to retrieve the remote files. My question is: Will this code delay the loading and rendering of the "more_content"-div?

Would it be better to enclose the ajax retrieval in a $(document).ready() block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will this code delay the loading and rendering of the "more_content"-div?

No, because the Ajax call is **asynchronous** (not blocking).

> Would it be better to enclose the ajax retrieval in a `$(document).ready()` block?

Yes. This will execute the Ajax call once the whole DOM is rendered.
<del>While it might work without, you cannot be 100% sure that element with ID `content` is available when the Ajax call returns.</del> *As @BiAiB pointed out, the element will be available. It is still good practice though.*

---

Btw, if you want your code to work in all browsers, you should use jQuery's `each` and not the built-in one:

```
jQuery.each(my_files, function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: params,
        jsonpCallback: "_populate_content",
    });
});
```

Maybe this is only a stripped down example, but does it make sense to load both URLs? The second call will override the results of the first one...

Comment: Actually, the #content node appear before the script, so it's ok in his case, but it's still better practice to use $(document).ready()  anyway, in case that former condition isn't satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no. Since you haven't defined 'async:false' in the .ajax() parameters, the javascript will execute asynchronously. This means that your my_files array will loop through and fire off asynchronous calls then continue on loading the page.

You may want to wrap your logic in $(document).ready(), but before doing that place a throbber in your more_content div to let the user know information is coming shortly.

Answer (score 0):

ajax calls are made asynchronous (unless you specify otherwise). So it won't delay your page loading.

Answer (score 0):

the ajax call is asynchronus, so no delay.
if you put it into a document ready block,
you enshure that the browser did render the whole page before doing the call ..

Answer (score -1):

Yes. The browser will block while those calls are made. You should instead do the work on page load so that the page is visible/rendered while the work is being done:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(my_files.each(function() {
     // etc...
  }));
});
```

Comment: As per http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, the .ajax() call will not block unless async:false is set.

Comment: Ah right, thanks for the clarification. Totally opposite to my understanding. Cheers!